# Geeking about a strange usage (=?)

Tags: meaning, etymology

#### Rolling On the Floor Geeking

A co-worker of mine and I had a meeting where a funny little exchange occurred, which I won't recount here, but when he was returning to the office, he sent me this text about the exchange:

[image: screenshot of 3 text messages, where coworker uses "geeking" to mean "laughing"]

In case the screenshot isn't clear, the text messages read:

> [co-worker]: I'm **geeking** while walking down the street at the "and he's really good too though" and then you going "well he's 26"
>
> [me]: **Geeking?**
>
> [co-worker]: **Laughing**

When he sent back "laughing", I assumed he had originally typed "laughing" or something similar to it, and autocorrect had corrupted the word and inserted "geeking".

But then, when he was telling the story to another co-worker in front of me, he said "geeking" again, aloud (i.e. **verbally**), and it was clear from context he did indeed mean "laughing".

#### No Geeking Matter

I have never before encountered "geeking" used to mean "laughing". It struck me as unusual and very interesting.  I checked a few dictionaries, and while I found all the senses I expected ("geeking out" == "obsessing over technical details"), nothing came even close to "laughing".

So I did an internet search for *geeking* + *laughing*. The search results included a few slang dictionaries and internet compendia, but most leads were red herrings, and I could only find once place with positive confirmation of this sense: Reddit.

Specifically, under [r/OutOfTheLoop](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/2pppai/what_does_geeking_mean/), we find [this question and accompanying response](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/2pppai/what_does_geeking_mean/cmzia5d/):

> #### What does "geeking" mean?
>
> if you mean geeking out, **I've always used it to express laughing a lot or uncontrollably**.

But that's as far as my research has been able to uncover this sense.

#### Geeking All the Way to the Bank

I asked my co-worker for his background and where he picked up this word.  In no particular order of importance:

- **American**, native speaker, neutral accent (I'm a native of NYC and his accent sounds neutral/unremarkable to me)
- Of Armenian descent, very close to the ex-pat Armenian community (but has never been to Armenia and doesn't speak Armenian)
- Born in California, moved around the world during his childhood (his dad's job was very international).
- After CA, moved to Japan (in infancy), then Oman, then the UK (London) for primary schooling, then the UAE and Qatar as an adolescent.
- University in Washington, DC.
- Was an **active member of a fraternity**, so he does have an inventory of "[bro](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bro)"-y vocabulary, used when applicable.
- Working professional (which is the register he maintains at the office).
- **Millennial**.

He says he's heard the word used by a variety of people, but he most closely associates it with a friend of his from [Eastchester, NY](http://www.eastchester.org/). He also speculates "maybe it's a millennial thing".

Of all the places he could have picked up the word, the "millennial" and "fraternity speak" theories ring truest to me; I am not persuaded his cosmopolitan upbringing is material. The word *feels* like young men's speech¹.

#### Last Geek

Have any of the experts on EL&U encountered *geeking* to mean *laughing* before? Is there **any evidence of a more widespread use**?

- If so, in what cultures or lects is the word deployed?
- What is its etymology, or,
- Failing a clear paper trail, what can we deduce about its likely origins?

---

¹ <sub>I am deliberately avoiding the characterization ["locker-room talk"](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/11/sports/what-exactly-is-locker-room-talk-let-an-expert-explain.html).</sub>

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=GEEKING

Comment: @HotLicks  Which UD definition are you pointing out? The “overly excited about something obscure” sense? That’s the standard one I’m familiar with that I mention in the “no geeking matter” section. If you mean there seems to be a path from “overly excited” to “intense laughter”, yes, that’s the kind of connection I was hoping people would draw out in their answers.

Comment: Not getting the title of this question...whether geeks laugh isn't an English Language Usage question, really.

Comment: From the question title: of course geeks laugh, they are human. It is what they find funny makes them geeks.

Comment: @KristinaLopez The title isn’t the question, the question is in the final section of the body here, with detailed sub questions. The answer to the titular question is of course “yes”, but the question implied by the title is “does that plain fact account for the observed usage of *geeking* for *laughing*”. I expected this was obvious, but maybe I’m wrong.

Comment: I got it...just being overly pedantic.  ;-)

Comment: Why is anybody close voting this?

Comment: @user159691 The close reason the first person selected (and the 2nd person selected in his wake) was “show your research”. Of course, I did that, in great detail.

Comment: The question talked all around the subject but didn't include the Urban Dictionary definition which was very clearly related.  Now the downvotes are locked unless an edit is made to the question.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I’m not worried about he downvotes. If you downvoted, don’t sweat it. It’s the close votes for a very topic, detailed, and researched question which seems inappropriate. I saw the top UD definition and I paraphrase it in the first para of the second section, and I explicitly mention reading slang dictionaries and internet compendia. I did my research, and I showed it.

Comment: Oops - you're so right. Definitely shouldn't be close-voted.

Comment: To me, *to geek* means *to act like a geek*; how does a geek act?  Rather socially awkward.  That could include laughing uproariously for something that would only seem funny to another geek.

Comment: @aparente001 The guy who described himself as *geeking* definitely doesn’t think of himself as a geek, and think you’d have a hard finding a third party observer who would categorize him as a geek. When he used the word, it was free of any connotations of nerdiness. It purely meant laughing. But definitely “social awkwardness” [may be part of this sense’s etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/422854/geeking-about-a-strange-usage/422862#comment1012196_422862), if not its modern denotation or even connotations.

Comment: @DanBron Sounds good.  After all, one doesn't have to be a geek, be viewed as a geek, or think of oneself as a geek, to act like a geek.

Comment: Sorry, I left something out.  *Geek* (noun and verb) also carry a sense of overenthusiasm.  That can make one look awkward (but a true geek would be oblivious, or wouldn't care). // Looking back at the dialogue, "geeking" also suggests "appreciating."

Comment: @aparente001 Yep, for sure. Some of that is discussed in the fantastic answers below. Worth reading if you haven’t already.

Comment: @DanBron - Sorry, too geeky for me!  (Too long and detailed.)

Comment: @aparente001 [You sure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/422854/geeking-about-a-strange-usage/422862#comment1012202_422862)? ;)

Comment: @DanBron - Example: Board Game Geeks = Board Game Enthusiasts.  Board Game Geeks are proud to be overenthusiastic and ridiculously knowledgeable about board games.  Board Game Geeks are hugely into board games.  https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Welcome_to_BoardGameGeek

Comment: @aparente001 I am familiar with that usage of *geek*, yes. The *you sure?* thing was a joke; the link went a comment on one of the answers which made the same joke you made in the comment it followed & responded to. I asked “you sure” because you said you didn’t want to read the answers, but he link demonstrated that if you did, you’d at a minimum see the same kind of humor as you evidently enjoy.

Comment: @DanBron - Sorry, yes, I did get that but I'm socially awkward....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Geeking in the dictionaries

The most reputable definition I could find is definition 4 for *geek* *v.1.* in [*Green's Dictionary of Slang*](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/s5ubndq).

> 4. (US campus, also geek out) to act stupidly, or in a way that counters the cultural norm.

More directly relevant than the definition provided in *GDoS* is one of the citations which references [*The Online Slang Dictionary*](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/geek).

> to **display an embarrassing amount of happiness**; to act like a geek (nerd).
>
> *She geeked when he asked her out.*

Notably, *The Online Slang Dictionary* allows user edits and submissions, but this sense of *geek* as a verb at least has Green's stamp of approval.

As for the etymology, *GDoS*'s placement of this sense under the definition related to **geeking out** suggests to me that its formation pattern was abbreviation of that phrase, which originated in computing culture and U.S. campus culture.

Attestations range from Connie Eble's *Campus Slang* cited in **1989** to a **2002** citation that uses the full phrase "geeking out."

[*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/geeked) provides this definition of **geeked** which is also relevant:

> filled with excitement or enthusiasm

*GDoS*, citing Eble, provides a similar definition of "geeked" that implies that someone is intoxicated by caffeine or stimulant medications.

> 1. excited
> 2. (US) intoxicated, specifically by caffeine or AHD medication.
>
> *‘Charlie was so geeked he alphabetized his book collection instead of doing his homework’.*

Eble added the second definition to her collection of campus slang in **2014**, making it a very recent sense.

The *OED* also defines *geeked* this way, but this sense still seems disparate from the verb meaning *laughing* or *displaying an embarrassing amount of happiness*.  Perhaps *GDoS*'s citation from the *OSD* is the most reputable recognition of this sense of *geek* as a verb that has yet been welcomed into the lexicon.

### Geeking on Twitter and Reddit

Judging from online uses, **geeking** appears to have a vast range of cutting-edge senses that extend beyond those that are outlined in curated dictionaries like *GDoS*.

**Drug senses - under the influence, often of stimulants like adderall, sometimes also marijuana or benzodiazepines.**

This sense is included in the dictionaries, but I thought I would cite a couple of examples of use to help illustrate the broad range of meanings "geeking" can connote.  This sense seems to be related to the sense meaning "excited," as in "I was so high I was geeking," and likely precedes the meaning referring to excitement (more on that in future edits).

> I don't know why people hate smoking alone, I be **GEEKING** when I'm high by myself I love that shit
>
> [I like smoking marijuana alone.]

- [@kenbrazy](https://twitter.com/kenbrazy/status/941027523550433285)

> Whoever said u cpudlnr ( drop xans in drank was wrong,, dropped 2 green hulks in my tropical sprite with a 4 of the wock and I'm **geeking hard** as a bitch.... boutta roll up this backwood and gp to sleep, don't thonk I'm waking back up today see yall tomorrow **GEEKGEEKGEEK**
>
> [Whoever said you couldn't mix [Xanax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alprazolam) with cough syrup (drank) was wrong, I just took two 2mg Xanax pills (2 green hulks) in my tropical sprite with ([cough syrup](http://www.wockhardtusa.com/index.php/liquid/product/99-hydrocodone-and-homatropine-syrup-cii)) and I'm **geeking** very hard...]

- [JoshNYC38, Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/opiates/comments/6qjm7b/geeking_so_hard_righ_now/)

**Craving or wanting badly, often as *geeking for* or *geeking over*.**

A few examples:

> i ain’t **geeking for** a relationship , it’s cool 2 have some1 tho

- [@KAYLAKAYLANI](https://twitter.com/KAYLAKAYLANI/status/940613704621723648)

> Wish somebody was **geeking over** me

- [@RoyalChvnel_](https://twitter.com/RoyalChvnel_/status/943740651270737920)

> **Geeking for** some lamb chops

- [@Bighomie_juan](https://twitter.com/Bighomie_juan/status/943871198039101440)

**Laughing**.  The sense in the question.

> I'm actually **geeking** so hard at everyone dragging the Kylie cosmetics brushes she is really out here trying to finesse $360... u thought sis

- [@LoveFromLiyax](https://twitter.com/LoveFromLiyax/status/942513334745817089) This user appears to be millenial, from Nashville, TN in the U.S.

> I’m **geeking**  he said “FUCK YOU REF! That was a bullshit call”

- [@*Stubs*](https://twitter.com/_Stubs_/status/940098295673659394)

Here is an interesting variation where "geeking" is transitive.  These sorts of variations seem common online.

> It’s been like an hour  it’s still **geeking me**

- [@AlmightyDetrick](https://twitter.com/AlmightyDetrick/status/940097652766621698)

In some cases, "geeking" appears to mean *joking* or *being ridiculous*.  This sense might be similar to the drug senses, as in "Oh, you must be high to say that."

> Oh Naw You **Geeking** Now

- [@iLike_GayGirls](https://twitter.com/iLike_GayGirls/status/940105355203305472)

The uses in all of these senses cited ***appear*** to be predominantly stated by people who are African American or well-versed in African American slang, who are young, and frequent users of slang.

---

<sub>Feedback on this answer is welcome, but please note that it is a work in progress.</sub>

Comment: Great research! From this plus the lower-ranking UD definitions, we might speculate “displaying obsession with nerdy stuff” -> “displaying happiness about socially unaccepted things” -> “displaying happiness to a socially unacceptable degree or in a socially unacceptable context or manner” -> [people do this while drunk or high so] “laughing when drunk or high” -> “laughing excessively because one is high [on marijuana]” -> “laughing excessively”. Maybe. Anyway super neat answer.

Comment: @DanBron thank you, it's a great and *well-researched* question as well. :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess we both like to *geek out* on obscure etymologies ;)

Comment: In re the bounty, your answer is grand, nothing wrong with it, but I'm hoping to (a) attract more eyeballs, and (b) establish as solid an etymology as the available data will allow. You have a head start, and I would love to see you expand this answer.

Comment: @DanBron I completely support both objectives.  I always love seeing multiple answers to a good question that warrants thorough investigation.  I will enjoy working on expanding this answer as well, regardless of whether I get the bounty.

Comment: I **love** all the additional color you chased up here. I was especially impressed at your translation of the super inebriated "green hulks" message.  And the African American thing surprises me - the guy I heard it from, and his circle of friends, are definitely what I'd label "preppy".

Comment: @DanBron thanks, I'm definitely geeking out on the question!  The tough part is connecting the dots.  "Geeking" or "geeking out" apparently originated in black culture (originally meaning heroin withdrawal per *GDoS*), and became adopted by campus / computing culture, and then from there it seemed to splinter and criss-cross into a whole bunch of different meanings.  But these senses all share something related to being "crazy" / "out of one's mind."  I'm curious how that landed on "laughing," and when.

Comment: @DanBron Fraternity slang seems to borrow from black slang quite a bit, *bro* being the most obvious example, but also *dope* (meaning excellent), *sick* (likewise), *word* (exclamation of approval or acknowledgment).  Maybe the fraternity connection makes sense then?

Comment: There is definitely overlap. But the people I know who say *dope* tend not to say *bro* and vice versa. The preppy kids will say *sick* but not *ill*, etc. but yeah I can definitely see a potential bridge.

Comment: @DanBron interesting, would you say that "bro" is preppy but "dope" is not?  So your friend would be the type that says "bro?"  Just curious.

Comment: Yes. Some preppies say *dope* but when they do it’s in a different register - consciously affected; imitative. A bit artificial.

Comment: Thank you for your hard work and research. I’ll definitely avail myself of your services again in the future!

Comment: @DanBron thanks for the bounty, I very much enjoyed researching this question, sorry I didn't add more in time, the holidays got me distracted.  I intend to make some edits to this post to make it more "complete," but I appreciate the recognition as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Geek both as a noun and as a verb appears to be a very productive term. It entered the AmE vocabulary at the beginning of the 20th century and has since then been used in different and also extreme contexts:

A bit of history from Wordorigns.com

[Geek](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/site/comments/geek/):

> ***By the beginning of the 20th century**, geek had crossed the Atlantic to America, where it took up residence in wider slang. From the comic strip A. Mutt (shortly afterward to become Mutt & Jeff) by H.C. Fisher appearing in the San Francisco Examiner of 28 April 1908:
>
> - *A geek who spends his spare time making Czar removers was slammed into the city cooler.*
>
> In America, the word also acquired a very specialized sense, that of a circus or carnival performer who engaged in outrageous acts on stage, such as biting the heads off live animals. From Billboard (Cincinnati) 25 October 1919:
>
> - *At Liberty—Snake charmer or geek man; would like to join show going south.*
>
> ***By the middle of the 20th century***, the term had lost any specific meaning in general slang use, being used simply as a disparaging label. At this time, it began to be applied to overly diligent students. From a letter by Jack Kerouac, 1 October 1957:
>
> - *Unbelievable number of events almost impossible to remember, including...Brooklyn College wanted me to lecture to eager students and big geek questions to answer.*
>
> The Kerouac quotation is something of an outlier, appearing much earlier than most of the other citations. Geek really came into its own in collegiate slang of the mid-1970s.
>
> ***And by the 1980s*** was being used to refer to aficionados of computers and other high-tech gadgetry, and it started losing some of its negative associations. From the Usenet group net.jokes of 20 February 1984:
>
> - *I was a lonely young computer geek With [sic] a program due ‘most every week.2Just one more source with relevant definitions.*

From the ‘80s onwards the term acquires new meanings, apparently based on its previous usages, for instance:

[Geek out](https://www.quora.com/What-does-geeking-out-mean):

> Today, to “geek out” means to act like a geek, and the meaning has expanded to include anyone who gets really excited about their favorite subject—especially if they are extremely or overly excited, and the subject is specialized or unusual. The meaning has expanded outside computers and technology, and you can geek out without being socially deficient.

(Quora)

As the  [The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.it/books?id=bbcBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA972&lpg=PA972&dq=geek%20partridge%20dictionary%20of%20unconventional%20english&source=bl&ots=PFtwzMZI9E&sig=5t0maVP9SIPUiq8T0D4c4mJCDT4&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp3tPgg5zYAhXFb1AKHcy2AhsQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=geek%20partridge%20dictionary%20of%20unconventional%20english&f=false) suggests:

***Geeked:***

> Jittery, childishly excited,  1984 US:

***To geek:***

> To display severe anxiety when coming off cocaine intoxication, 1993 US.
>
> To act foolishly,  1998 US

The meaning of laughing appears to be related to that of the effect   drugs,  and a number of informal online sources appear to suggest that relationship. This usage may have evolved in recent years and its place of origin is unclear. One source below refers to it as a slang typical of Maryland:

***[to geeked](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/site/comments/geek/)*** from (azdictionary.com):

> Meaning: happy or excited 
>   or being high or "geeked up"
>
> Example: "nigga,you to geeked!" 
>   "i am to geeked."

***[Geek](https://books.google.it/books?id=bbcBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA972&lpg=PA972&dq=geek%20partridge%20dictionary%20of%20unconventional%20english&source=bl&ots=PFtwzMZI9E&sig=5t0maVP9SIPUiq8T0D4c4mJCDT4&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp3tPgg5zYAhXFb1AKHcy2AhsQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=geek%20partridge%20dictionary%20of%20unconventional%20english&f=false)*** can be used in 2 different ways: from  (definedictionarymeaning.com)

> 1- Geek = the state of being amusing or humorous.
>
> 2- Geeking = When a person is really fucked up on any kind of drug.

The following site suggests that  “geeking” is a  Maryland slang: from (theodysseyonline.com)

> ***[Geeking](https://www.theodysseyonline.com/maryland-slang-14-words-only-true-maryland-teens-know?utm_expid=.oW2L-b3SQF-m5a-dPEU77g.0&utm_referrer=)*** :If you find something funny and start hysterically laughing or lol-ing, then you are geeking.

As for [Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/hashtag/geeking), there is the *#geeking*  with a few funny messages for instance:

> Petr Bulkhak
>   @pbulkhak
>   ·
>   21 dic
>   Religion on the block chain is an untapped market. #geeking
>
> GallantSector
>   @GallantSector
>   Coworker said I look like a dude from #AssassinsCreed with my hood on while I was working.  #Geeking

Comment: Awesome, definitely extending the etymology backwards to its earlier, pre-laughing/fucked-up-on-drugs glosses. Thank you for putting all the work in to develop this illuminating answer!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - well, the static image doesn’t add much to the meaning described, so I’ll remove it.